# Why i am able to read, write firestore even when it is not public?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I Testing my app from Android Studio. In the middle i deleted all my Authenticatin account manually from firebase, still i am able to do database operation. Security rule in my collection--

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting an account in the Firebase Auth console does not immediately invalidate the current auth ID token of any currently signed in users.  The user will be able to use their ID token for up to an hour after it was last refreshed.  That token is good enough to pass rules that require auth as you show here.

If you sign out, the ID token will be deleted, and they won't be able to query with these rules.  Or, if the token expires and needs to be refreshed, they will not be able to query.

There is no way to write rules that immediately locks out users who accounts have been deleted.